# Best way to incrementally convert microseconds to their respective conversions in python?

Tags: python

I currently have a pre-defined dictionary (ignore the letters). I want the conversions to be more robust, though. Say 33000000 microseconds gets inputted and knows to convert to 33 seconds. Then any microsecond input over a minute, but under an hour shows as minutes, etc. Is it possible to get this coded without needing this pre-defined dictionary? Preferably a function that takes in a microsecond input and then outputs the proper conversion.

```
'A100.txt'                          :'100 us',
'B500.txt'                          :'500 us',
'C1000.txt'                         :'1 ms',
'D4000.txt'                         :'4 ms',
'E5000.txt'                         :'10 ms',
'F30000.txt'                        :'30 ms',
'G100000.txt'                       :'100 ms',
'H300000.txt'                       :'300 ms',
'I1000000.txt'                      :'1 sec',
'J3000000.txt'                      :'3 secs',
'K10000000.txt'                     :'10 secs',
'L30000000.txt'                     :'30 secs',
'M60000000.txt'                     :'1 min',
'N180000000.txt'                    :'3 mins',
'O600000000.txt'                    :'10 mins',
'P1800000000.txt'                   :'30  mins',
'Q3600000000.txt'                   :'1 hr',
'R7200000000.txt'                   :'2 hrs',
'S14400000000.txt'                  :'4 hrs'}
```

Comment: Instead of explicitly defining each possible value, separate it in ranges that you want to convert to each unit. For example, 1 to 999 keep in microseconds, 1000 to 999999 convert to milliseconds, etc. Then using some algebra you can calculate the new converted value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a long string of `if` statements. Since there is no `switch` statement in Python, and a dictionary cannot be used for `>` and `<`, this is the best solution.

Something you might make would be:

```
def convert(text):
  t = int(text)
  if t<1000: #millisecond
    return str(t)+' us'
  elif t<1000000: #second
    return str(int(t/1000))+' ms'
  elif t==1000000: #is a second
    return '1 sec'
  #etc.
```

Alternate Solution:

```
units = [("us", 1), ("ms", 1000), ("sec", 1000000)...]
for string, divisor in units:
  if t==divisor:
    return "1 "+string
  elif t>divisor:
    if round(float(t)/divisor)==1:
      return "1 "+string
    else:
      return str(int(round(float(t)/divisor)))+string+"s"
```

Hopefully this will be a better trade off between compactness, scalability, and readability.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I like this way. Was trying to get someone to help me look at this a little differently and you did just that!

Comment: @rern Improved my answer. Please take a look. Not so blobby anymore.

Comment: Let's say `t=2000`, your alternate solution will return "2000uss". You'd have to traverse your units in reverse order for the logic to work.

Answer (score 3):

This allows you to add conversions in a relatively natural way for strictly ascending unit stacks. It's a little more generic than big block of ifs.

```
units = [[1000, 'us'], 
         [1000, 'ms'], 
         [60, 's'], 
         [60, 'min'], 
         [24, 'h'], 
         [365, 'day'], 
         [None, 'year']]

def convert(quantity):
    divisor = 1
    for factor, name in units:
        if factor is None or quantity < divisor*factor:
            return "{} {}".format(quantity/divisor, name)
        divisor *= factor
```

Answer (score 1):

@Bcdan says "this is about as compact as possible". Challenge accepted.

```
>>> l = [("micro",1),("milli",1000),("s",1000),("m",60),("h",60)]
>>> d = {"micro":33000000}
>>> for i in range(1,len(l)): d[l[i][0]],d[l[i-1][0]] = divmod(d[l[i-1][0]],l[i][1])
>>> d
{'m': 0, 's': 33, 'h': 0, 'milli': 0, 'micro': 0}
```

Don't know how useful that is to you, but I think it's neat. Not that it's readable or makes any sense...

Comment: @MarkRansom I didn't know about that site! Thanks for the heads up, it looks fun.

Comment: @rern look what you started http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52684/format-microseconds-as-hoursminutesseconds-etc

Comment: @Sam ahhaha, that's hilarious.

Comment: Also, my solution can be implemented as a separate utility module. **Readability is important,  too!!** ;)

Comment: I found the code golf independently and those are always so convoluted and silly pieces of code!!

Comment: I know this isn't exactly the place but in case you're interested in golfing tips: You can lose the space after `:` and on either side of every `=`. Since you know `len(l)` will be 4, you can hardcode that to get `range(1,4)`. To save another two bytes, use `range(3)` and change every `i` to `i+1` (or remove the `-1`). To save even more, drop the `range` entirely! `for i in 0,1,2:` works (or `1,2,3` if you don't do the `+1` thing from earlier).