# Converting time efficiently in Python

Tags: python

I have a program that does some parsing and takes in time in a microsecond format. However, when reading this data, it's not very pretty to see 10000000000 microseconds. Something like x seconds, or x minutes, looks better.

So.. I built this:

```
def convert_micro_input(micro_time):
    t = int(micro_time)
    if t<1000: #millisecond
        return str(t) +' us'
    elif t<1000000: #second
        return str(int(t/1000))         +   ' ms'
    elif t<60000000: #is a second
        return str(int(t/1000000))      +   ' second(s)'
    elif t<3600000000:
        return str(int(t/60000000))     +   ' minute(s)'
    elif t<86400000000:
        return str(int(t/3600000000))   +   ' hour(s)'
    elif t<604800000000:
        return str(int(t/86400000000))  +   ' day(s)'
    else:
        print 'Exceeded Time Conversion Possibilities'
        return None
```

Now, in my eyes, this looks fine, however, my boss wasn't satisfied. He said the numbers are confusing in terms of readability if someone were to come edit this in a year and he said to make this happen in a while loop.

So, with that being said. Under these constraints, I am wondering at how to implement this same logic into a more readable (maybe using python equivalent of a macro) form and also put it in a while loop.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Your boss is right about the large numbers. Typically the kind of thing you have is not done with precomputed numbers, but spelled out with easier to follow multplications. This helps with later debugging and mitigates risk. For instance, how many seconds are in a day? I don't know off the top of my head but if I see `60 * 60 * 24` I know the code is right. Likewise, is 360000000 really the correct number on your second to last conversion? No, it's not, because I chopped off a zero and you probably didn't even notice!

Comment: Also using str.format would be a little more visually appealing `'{}us'.format(t)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to incrementally convert microseconds to their respective conversions in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251377/best-way-to-incrementally-convert-microseconds-to-their-respective-conversions-i)

Comment: Your boss wasn't satisfied because you are using what are referred to as "[magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))."

Comment: I could easily do this with a while loop, but it wouldn't be any easier to read or modify once the magic numbers are gone. Why is that such a hard requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python has this facility built into itself

```
from datetime import timedelta
for t in all_times_in_us:
    print timedelta(seconds=t/1000000.0)
```

taking advantage of that is the easiest(and most readable) way I think. that said if you really want to you can make it more readable by defining some constants at the top (or in a time_util.py file or something)

```
MICROSECOND=1
MILLISECOND=MICROSECOND*1000
SECOND=MS*1000
MINUTE=SECOND*60
HOUR=MINUTE*60
DAY=HOUR*24
WEEK=DAY*7
```

and use these values instead that way it is very clear what they are

eg

```
if t < MILLISECOND: 
    return "{time} us".format(time=t)
elif t < SECOND:
    return  "{time} ms".format(time=t//MILLISECOND)
elif t < MINUTE:
    return  "{time} seconds".format(time=t//SECOND)
...
```

Comment: I need it in a while and I need to use similar conversion connotation to that of two-bit alchemist from above

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html) module with a `timedelta` object.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> us = 96000000
>>> mytime = datetime.timedelta(microseconds=us)
>>> mytime.seconds
96
```